# enable cache for jQuery.i18n.properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, internationalization

I'm trying to enable cache to avoid reloading Messages.properties files each time when it's needed.

```
jQuery.i18n.properties({
    name: 'Messages',
    path: '../capability/',
    mode: 'both',
    language: 'en',
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    callback: function(){ document.title = Messages.cap_4; }
    });
```

When I inspect in firefox I have some cached Messages.properties files with the 304 code even if the browser still load the same file more than once.
[image]

and when I inspect in chrome all the messages.properties files are called each time when it needed and no one of them is cached.
[image]
do I get it wrong? or this is a knowing bug ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Chrome testing, all of Message.properties files were actually read from cache (notice the "from disk cache" in Size column).
The difference between 200 and 304 responses you see come from the "cache expiration time".
When the client makes a new request (e.g. GET Message.properties) and your cache is not expired yet, the browser will try to read the content from cache instead of requesting the server, this case will return a 200 with "from disk cache" comment.
In the other case, when your cache is expired, the browser sends GET request to server, then there are 2 cases:

- There is no new update in that file so server returns a 304 (304 means the file in server is not changed since the last time so the browser can keep reading the cache instead).
- There is new change in the file, then server will return a 200 with new file content to client.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Despite the "cache" boolean, the property file is downloaded from the server each time we reload the page (Cache is enabled, I see the 200 status and it take most of my loading time when I simulate a slow network with Chrome).